# неразрешенный внешний символ или ошибка в namespace

Tags: c++

Подскажите пожалуйста понять, в чем именно состоит ошибка "неразрешенный внешний символ":

> Ошибка    LNK2001 неразрешенный внешний символ "class
> namespace1::my_class namespace1::my_class_"
> (?my_class_@namespace1@@3Vmy_class@1@A).

main.cpp

```
 #include <iostream> 
    #include "My_function.h"
    
    
    int main()
    {
    
        My_function();
    
    }
```

my_function.cpp

```
 #include "my_class.h"
    #include "My_function_second.h"
    
    
    
    
        thread_local namespace1::my_class my_class_;
    
    
        void My_function()
        {
            namespace1::My_function_second();
        }
```

My_function_second.cpp

```
 #include "my_class.h"
    
    
    namespace namespace1
    {
    
        extern thread_local my_class my_class_;
    
    
        void My_function_second()
        {
            my_class_.my_void();
        }
    
    }
```

my_class.h

```
 namespace namespace1
    {
    
    
        class my_class
        {
    
        public:
    
            void my_void()
            {
            }
    
        };
    
    
    }
```

Если убрать namespace1, то ошибка пропадает, то есть ошибка явно в namespace1, но я не могу понять  чем именно то.

Comment: Делайте геттер.

Comment: @user7860670, а в чем именно ошибка ?

Comment: В том что объявление extern в .cpp

Comment: @user7860670, но, если я namespace убираю, то вроде бы проблем с объявлением extern в .cpp - нету.

Comment: Ну так правильно, если объявлять переменную вне пространства имен, то имеющееся определение (которое определяет `::my_class_`) будет соответствовать.

Comment: @user7860670, ну std::string к примеру - тоже же вне пространства имен объявляется ?

Comment: Не понял, тут же нигде нет `std::string`.

Comment: @user7860670, я имел ввиду, если я заменю "namespace1::my_class my_class_" на std::string и extern  std::string, то в чем будет разница ?

Comment: Ничего не понятно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В `thread_local namespace1::my_class my_class_;`, `namespace1::` действует только на тип, а не на саму переменную.

Правильно - вот так:

```
thread_local namespace1::my_class namespace1::my_class_;
```

Или так:

```
namespace namespace1
{
    thread_local my_class my_class_;
}
```

Comment: а лучше всего изменить  подход....

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, на всякий случай, но первый вариант thread_local namespace1::my_class namespace1::my_class_; - не работает.  Вы же не пишите std::string std::my_string.  Компилятор такое не скомпилирует же.

Comment: @Optimus1 Все работает. Пример: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/PGzPcTWEx

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, а VS2019 ругается :(

Comment: @Optimus1 Хмм, а тут работает: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/ej8cb56ba